# How to scroll in the layer menu while grabbing a layer?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, workflow

My layer list is very big and sometimes when I duplicate a layer, I need to move it far away but I have to bring it near the edge to activate the slow autoscroll.

It would be far more convenient if I could scroll with the mouse wheel while grabbing something.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: cheat. copy it to a new document, scroll to where you want it, copy it back.

Comment: What program are you talking about? There are a many programs within CS6 that have layers

Comment: I'm guessing you are talking about photoshop, since your last question was about photoshop. In photoshop there is `Layers > Arrange` and in there:  `Send to front, Send forward, Send backward, Send to back`. If you don't have US keyboard, you most likely need to change the shortcut keys. `Send forward` and `Send backward` "jump over" collapsed groups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't. The method suggested by Joonas and elaborated by Rachuru is a good option for many cases. When that isn't suitable, here's another option you can try.

Not the ideal solution you're asking for, but an option that can help in situations where you have up to 60 layers in Illustrator or maybe 40 in Photoshop - any more and it'd still be the tedious slow scroll:

1. Move your layers panel to the top of the list by click-dragging it upwards.
2. Then use the panel resize utility as you can see in the screenshot, and drag that panel height as far down as it can go.

On my screen I (quickly - could be wrong) count 32 layers that I can drag up and down immediately.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not possible what exactly you want—scroll with the mousewheel while grabbing something.

You can use these methods for some convience, as @Joonas mentioned in the comments

**Using the Arrange command.** If you’ve got one or more layers activated, you can choose `Layer > Arrange` to move them somewhere else in the layer stack. Depending on the location of the layer(s) in the Layers panel, you can choose from these commands:

- **Bring to Front** moves the layer(s) all the way to the top of the layer stack. Keyboard shortcut: <kbd>⌘ / Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>]</kbd>.
- **Bring Forward** moves the layer(s) up one level. Keyboard shortcut: <kbd>⌘ / Control</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>.
- **Send Backward** sends the layer(s) down one level. Keyboard shortcut: <kbd>⌘ / Control</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>.
- **Send to Back** sends the layer(s) all the way to the bottom of the layer stack (or just above the Background layer, if you’ve got one). Keyboard shortcut: <kbd>⌘ / Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>.
- **Reverse**. If you’ve got two or more layers activated, this command inverts the stacking order of the active layers. You probably won’t use this command very often, but give it a try just for fun; it can produce some mildly interesting results. (There’s no keyboard shortcut for this one).

Source from

https://www.inkling.com/read/photoshop-cs6-missing-manual-lesa-snider-1st/chapter-3/layer-basics

Comment: Hey Rachuru, it seems you borrowed these instructions from somewhere, possibly "Photoshop CS6: The Missing Manual"? It's alright to quote source material, but we need to explicitly cite the reference so that we're not plagiarizing. Please edit in a reference to where you found these instructions.

Comment: Copying answers from textbooks word for word is considered plagiarism.  If you are going to reference material you need to post the source and word it in your manner that makes it your own.  Source: Photoshop CC Missing Manual

Comment: @Matt it's only plagiarism when it's not attributed to its source. It doesn't matter if you copy it word for word, as long as you attribute it.